# ExpandoMetaClass in Grails to override behavior in a Java library?

Tags: grails, groovy, expandometaclass

I'm using Grails with third-party java libraries, and I'd like to override behavior in one of those libraries.

I've attempted to do this in Bootstrap.groovy, like so:

```
    // class overrides
    ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()
    SimpleStringFilter.metaClass.passesFilter = {Object itemId, Item item ->
        final Property<?> p = item.getItemProperty(propertyId);
        if (p == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Object propertyValue = p.getValue();
        if (propertyValue == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final String value = ignoreCase ? propertyValue.toString()
                .toLowerCase() : propertyValue.toString();
        if (onlyMatchPrefix) {
            if (!value.startsWith(filterString)) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (!value.contains(filterString)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I know for a fact that the method passesFilter in the SimpleStringFilter class gets called, but I've set a breakpoint in my code above and it's never hit.

For reference, the signature of the java method is:

```
public boolean passesFilter(Object itemId, Item item)
```

So, can one actually override behavior in java libraries with ExpandoMetaClass globally? Can someone explain the behavior and nuances of using it in this way?

Thanks!

Comment: fyi - you can delete `ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()` since Grails calls that early in the startup process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that Java classes don't invoke `metaClass`. Groovy can't override method calls to Java classes using `metaClass`.

This is a common misunderstanding when you see something like this:

```
def object = new MyJavaObject()
object.metaClass.someMethod = { ... }
```

What is actually happening above is you are creating a Groovy object that wraps the `MyJavaObject` which then allows that instance to invoke through metaClass.

Comment: Partly true - it can work, but only for calls from Groovy to the Java methods, since all Groovy method calls run through the MOP. But if a Java class calls this method, there's no Groovy in the mix, and it will call the real method. You'd need AOP for that.